# Django import-export generate username before user csv upload

Tags: django, csv, django-import-export

I need to bulk generate users for my app from a csv file. The csv I have contains the following fields:

*last_name, first_name, email*

To generate the username I have a function which I was hoping to use in a 'dehydrate' method. The dehydrate method works only with exports, not imports.

**[edit]** 
After @sanca-kembang gave the answer below this is what I ended up doing. The example below works perfectly (django 1.10.5, python 3.6.0).

*tools.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def generate_username(first_name, last_name):

    fname = first_name.lower()
    lname = last_name.lower()

    prefix = "%s%s" % (fname[0], lname)
    username = prefix
    i = 2
    while User.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
        username = "%s%d" % (prefix, i)
        i += 1
    return username
```

*admin.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from import_export import resources, widgets
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from .tools import generate_username


class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        fields = ('id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'email', 'username')

    def import_obj(self, obj, data, dry_run):
        first_name = data.get('first_name')
        last_name = data.get('last_name')
        username = generate_username(first_name, last_name)
        for field in self.get_fields():
            if isinstance(field.widget, widgets.ManyToManyWidget):
                continue
            if field.column_name == 'username':
                data.update({'username': username})
            print(obj)

            self.import_field(field, obj, data)

class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):  
    resource_class = UserResource     

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error, please clarify?

Comment: No error, the dehydrate method is simply ignored when trying to import. Works fine on export, though. Is it supposed to work on import?

Comment: You can use a `pre_save` or a `post_save` django signal to do this.

Comment: @Bitonator can you present a short example of pre_save? I checked the documentation of the django import-export site and it's quite frugal about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I check at the source, and I found a different method between import and export... the function of `export_field` has `dehydrate_` attribute, but not for `import_field`...

**Export:** https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L590-L595

```
def export_field(self, field, obj):
    field_name = self.get_field_name(field)
    method = getattr(self, 'dehydrate_%s' % field_name, None)
    if method is not None:
        return method(obj)
    return field.export(obj)
```

**Import:** https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L315-L321

```
def import_field(self, field, obj, data):
    """
    Calls :meth:`import_export.fields.Field.save` if ``Field.attribute``
    and ``Field.column_name`` are found in ``data``.
    """
    if field.attribute and field.column_name in data:
        field.save(obj, data)
```

I think you need to overwrite the function of [`import_obj`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L323), an example for your case:

```
from import_export import resources, widgets
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

# your package imported

class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        ....

    def dehydrate_username(self, user):
         # your unfinish code got here, 
         # if you want to enable for export mode...
         # username = generate_username_function here
         return username

    def import_obj(self, obj, data, dry_run):
        """
        Traverses every field in this Resource and calls
        :meth:`~import_export.resources.Resource.import_field`.
        """
        for field in self.get_fields():
            if isinstance(field.widget, widgets.ManyToManyWidget):
                continue

            # find specific `field_name`
            # param of `data` is OrderDict
            if field.column_name == 'username':
                data.update({'username': 'Hello %s' % data.get('username')})
            # checkout the changed object
            print(obj)

            self.import_field(field, obj, data)
```

Here is my test...

[image: test import export]

> See also this similiar issue; https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/51

Hope it helpful..